# Breaking Apart SQL statements

Tags: mysql, sql

For someone starting to use more advanced SQL queries, what are some good tips for interpreting statements and understanding the logic behind them?

For example, when extracting the latest 7 days of data to visualize:

```
case when `date` >= SUBDATE(`max_date`, interval 7 day) and
          `date` <= `max_date` 
     then 'Yes' 
     else 'No' 
end
```

Why does it need "and `date`"? Most online examples do not have this... And how does one break this down for a clear understanding of how each element contributes to the statement?

Thank you!

Comment: The 'and' goes with the 'where' as an extra bit of subsetting, and the 'date' is the column name that is compared in that extra bit of subsetting. Does that help? All SQL statements are different, so it's very unlikely that an online example will contain the same column names and criteria as your statement. Also it's quite uncommon for a column to be called 'date' as this is a reserved name in some database products. P.S. a relational database design textbook would be a good place to start I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

Your code is checking for dates within 7 days of the *maximum* in the data.  Because you know the maximum date, these are equivalent:

```
`date` >= SUBDATE(`max_date`, interval 7 day) and `date` <= `max_date` 
`date` >= SUBDATE(`max_date`, interval 7 day)
```

The second condition is always true.  Of course, I'm assuming that `max_date` is the maximum value of `date`.  If not, then you need both comparisons.

This is different from the most recent 7 days, which most people would interpret relative to the current date.  That would be more like:

```
case when `date` >= SUBDATE(curdate(), interval 7 day) and
          `date` <= curdate()
     then 'Yes' 
     else 'No' 
end
```

(Note:  For one week, you might want `interval 6 day`, but I'm ignoring boundary conditions on the logic.)  If the `date`s represent things that have happened, they are necessarily in the past, so the second comparison is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!

Yes, in this case the data lags by a few days and thus is not the current date, but good to know.

To better understand the functionality, could you expand on "because you know the maximum date"? i.e. what is the functionality of "and `date` <= `max_date`"?

Comment: @user10463191 . . . It is redundant if `max_date` is, indeed, the maximum value of `date` in the same table.